# How do I specify custom date range in FullCalendar v2.1.1?

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I am in need to rendering the custom view of FullCalendar.

Generally month starts from 1 and ends at 28,29,30 or 31.

Now I want to give the startdate and enddate to the FullCalendar, i.e. 10 Nov - 09 Dec (Custom Month)

**I expect that FullCalendar will display the calendar view starting from 10 Nov - 09 Dec.**

Month label is not necessary, it can be hidden, I just want a  view with this date range.

Anyone have any solutions?

Comment: You can't do this in the "month" type view unfortunately, because it only displays fixed months. It can be done for agenda and list-style views though, if you upgrade to v3.3 or above, and use visibleRange (https://fullcalendar.io/docs/current_date/visibleRange/).

Comment: @ADson Looking forward to upgrade it then, thanks for reply.

Comment: @ADyson Hello there, today I have upgraded fullCalendar.js to 3.3.0, you were right, custom date is possible only for agenda or list-views, is there any work around to set the custom range for month view, (Like I want the UI like month view but with custom start and end dates, it can be between months too !! i.e 11-DEC-2017 to 10-JAN-2018). Appreciate your help.

Comment: No, there's no workaround that I know of, it's a completely fixed display format. It's designed to display a month, from the start of the month, like a traditional paper calendar that people place in their houses. Personally I think if you were to start messing with that, it would be confusing because people (at least in my culture anyway) have a certain set expectation of what that grid-style layout in a calendar will represent.

Comment: If you _really_ want to make a grid in a similar way with multiple rows, but which represents a custom set of days, then I guess you could copy and the modify the existing "month" view code from the fullCalendar source, and then adapt it to your needs and add it as a "custom view" - see the lower half of this page https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/ - but that's quite a complex task.

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for your precious time mate, I love that part of customizing the fullCalendar.js according to my need, I've visited the link you mentioned, went through the lower half as well, I guess I will be able to make a custom view in fullcalendar.js file, but have a few questions, one of them is How will I specify custom date range in my code, using visibleRange? if yes, then in which function I should specify this. Appreciate your help in a greater way pal.

Comment: I have no idea about that unfortunately, I haven't studied the source code at all, I just know from the documentation that it's theoretically possible. Perhaps you could study the code for the views which do support visibleRange and see how they do it.

Comment: @ADyson okay pal, not an issue, thanks for your help, appreciate your all efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do one thing
For fullcalendar.js

Just comment one line

```
start.startOf(customAlignment || unit)
```

and pass

> "defaultDate"

while creating fullcalendar

Comment: Bingo !!! That worked like a charm, thanks for your help, loved it. How did you figure this out? It is very hard to get this much specific solution. Marked as answer.

Comment: Thank you  :)
You can also conditionally use it like if you don't get defaultDate then use

start.startOf(customAlignment || unit) else not

Comment: Alright, thanks for your time, appreciate your efforts. I'll surely try that too !